# How to simply display a value on a jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I realize variations of this question are all over, but are not meeting my specific needs and noobness.

No matter what I try in the .jsp file, I am always displaying blank strings.  I'm not sure if I'm not even passing the value, or if I'm trying to display it incorrectly.

The controller method that calls the page:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/showOffice/{officeId}", method=RequestMethod.GET) 
    public ModelAndView showOfficePage(@PathVariable("officeId") Long officeId, HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println("The office being found is: " + officeId.toString());
        Office office = officeServiceImpl.find(officeId);
        String officeName = office.getOfficeName();
        System.out.println("The office name that should be displayed is: " + officeName);
        ModelAndView result = new ModelAndView("showOffice", "office", office);
        request.setAttribute("officeName", officeName);
        return result;
    }
```

The jsp file (which calls includes the include.jsp which has `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`:

```
<t:genericpage>
<t:header></t:header>
<h1>Office Name:<c:out value="${request.officeName}" /> </h1>
</t:genericpage>
```

Here's the link that I press to show the button:

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/showOffice/${10}" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Find An Office</a>
```

Logging shows that the appropriate value is assigned to `officeName` in the controller method.

Can anybody advise me here?  Thanks.

Comment: What's your problem again?

Comment: @GustavoSuarez, good call.  I updated the first part of the post with the problem.

Comment: Did you try -> <c:out value="${officeName}" />

Comment: are u getting empty string on this pageContext.request.contextPath?

Comment: @Gayathri,  you got it.  Feel free to add as answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in the request scope, So you should be able to get it with

```
<c:out value="${officeName}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you use 10 as a variable

> > `<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/showOffice/`**${10**}`"`

If you need just Office #10 then try

`<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/showOffice/`**10**`"`

Comment: You're right.  It's simply a placeholder until I start placing links for > 1 objects.  Really just proving to myself that it would work as variable.